# Flickr api doesn't return the estimated value

Tags: flickr

I am using flickr api in order to count the how many times a tag occur. I want this information in order to calculate the Normalized Google Distance. I am using this query in my java code:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXX&format=json&tags=bank
```

But i don't get good results. For example when i search "bank" the count value is 357439, when i search "credit" the count value is 59288, but when i am search for "bank credit" the count value is only 2. When i searching with the search box at flickr.com for "bank credit" i get a lot of results. But as far as i can see the query it uses is

```
http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=bank%20credit
```

which i am not able to use through my java code. I am trying to pass this

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXX&format=json&q=bank
```

and it says

> Parameterless searches have been disabled. Please use flickr.photos.getRecent instead
>   How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generated url is incorrect

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXX&format=json&q=bank
```

is missing the question mark

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXX&format=json&q=bank
```

**UPDATE based on OP comments:**

I didn't see you had the question mark on the top url string. Looking at it again, I did realize you are not passing in any valid parameters. "q" isn't one of the listed parameters on the [search api page](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html). Try something like below to search photos with "bank" tag

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXX&format=json&tags=bank
```

or one with bank in description/title

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXX&format=json&text=bank
```

Comment: I didn't paste the correst query. Sorry. The quetion mark isn't missing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. but when I added media = photos in the parameters, it got resolved.
e.g. :

```
baseurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
params_d['api_key'] = 'XXXXXXX'
params_d['method'] = 'flickr.photos.search'
params_d['tag'] = "river,mountains"
params_d['tag_mode'] = 'all'
params_d['per_page'] = 5
params_d['media'] = "photos"
params_d['nojsoncallback'] = 1
params_d['format'] = 'json'

resp = requests.get(baseurl, params = params_d)
```